# Why is reason that synchronized lock not working on String concatenation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, string-pool

I am using the following code. I am not able to achieve synchronization. As per me String pool concept should have worked here.

I want to know the reason behind the problem, not the alternatives to it.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class SynchronizationBug {
    private static Map<String,Date> concurrentMap=new ConcurrentHashMap();
    
    public static void start(String processId) throws InterruptedException{
        final String lock="log"+processId;
        synchronized (lock) {
            if(concurrentMap.containsKey(processId)) {
                System.out.println("Process is already working and started at "+concurrentMap.get(processId));
                return;
            }       
            concurrentMap.put(processId,new Date());
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
//      System.out.println(isPrime(10));
        final String pId="p1";
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    start(pId);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    start(pId);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        
        for (String s:concurrentMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(s+" - "+concurrentMap.get(s));
        }
    }
    
}
```

If I take a lock on processId which is passed as a method parameter, then things are working as expected.
What is the reason for this behaviour of Java. I have tested this on Java8 Eclipse IDE.

**EDIT:**
If String pool concept has no relevance then how does the following code work fine.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class SynchronizationBug {
    private static Map<String,Date> concurrentMap=new ConcurrentHashMap();
    
    public static void start(String processId) throws InterruptedException{
        final String lock="log"+processId;
        synchronized (processId) {
            if(concurrentMap.containsKey(processId)) {
                System.out.println("Process is already working and started at "+concurrentMap.get(processId));
                return;
            }       
            concurrentMap.put(processId,new Date());
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
//      System.out.println(isPrime(10));
        final String pId1="p1";
        final String pId2="p1";
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    start(pId1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    start(pId2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        
        for (String s:concurrentMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(s+" - "+concurrentMap.get(s));
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here I am passing two different string objects with same value.Due to their same reference in the pool the locking is working fine .
Please correct me....

Comment: Where do you see a _string pool concept_ here? In fact, you are obviously synchronizing on a different object, each time your method `start` is called.

Comment: _"As per me String pool concept should have worked here."_ Why do you think that? Because it doesn't.

Comment: The reason for the "edit" code works is that you're locking on `processId`, not `lock`. It's not because you're passing two different string objects, because - and this actually is because of the string pool - `pId1` and `pId2` have the same value; and that's the value you are locking on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that String concatenation, if the operands are not both compile-time constant expressions, results in a new instance of String being created. See [here in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.29).

Method parameters are not compile-time constant expressions, since the method can be called with any value for the parameter.

And, because the current thread is the only thread which has access to this newly-created String, synchronizing on it has no effect.

Since you say you don't want to know the alternatives, I'll stop there.

---

You seem unconvinced, despite my pointing to the relevant part of the spec, that the strings you are synchronizing on are different. Try adding this line, right before the `synchronized`:

```
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(lock));  // Add this
    synchronized (lock) {
      // ...
```

This will print out the "identity hash code" of the lock, which isn't the same as `lock.hashCode()`, which is based on the value of the string. This will show that `synchronized` is synchronizing on different values (unless you're *exceptionally* lucky/unlucky, since hash collisions are unlikely but possible).